# Linked List in C, not linking properly

Tags: c, linked-list

So I am trying to link a list together from user input their own file , but when I try printing it only prints the the first line, I believe the problem lies somewhere below in my code fragment, I think currp is not getting currp-next.

```
while ((fscanf( fpin, "'%[^']' %f %f %d" ,currp->name, &currp->cost,
                                        &currp->weight, &currp->dam) ==4 ))
        {
                prev = currp;
                currp->next = malloc(sizeof(item_t));
                assert(currp->next);
                currp = currp->next;
        }

        prev->next = NULL;
        free(currp);
        fclose(fpin);

        return (itb);
```

Comment: do you mind showing more code? such as the code for printing the list

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is, where'd the head of my list go? Hm.... maybe *that's* why you're only getting one value; *the last one*. regardless, post valid code that **reproduces the issue** or this is likely going to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess currp does get next , but you just don't assign it . 
Just check it , 
Add a printf of currp->next as an integer 
It will represent it's address if address changes 
Then the problem is in assertion .